# Viewer para PDF com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, google-chrome

Como eu faço para abrir PDF no google chrome por jquery sem a necessidade de instalação de plugins? Não há a necessidade de código fonte, apenas como devo fazer. Pode ser um link e etc...

Comment: Sem plugin de PDF não dá pra abrir PDF. É mais ou menos querer ouvir som sem alto falantes. Você teria que converter no servidor o PDF para HTML como o Gmail, Outlook, Office Web fazem e como o jQuery só roda no cliente, não há solução para a sua pergunta.

Comment: @MarcosRegis, eu já consegui um e estou homologando. O TobyMosque também me enviou um que ainda não tive a oportunidade de testar, pois ainda estou testando o que eu havia conseguido anteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

Criei um link apontando para um pfd e usei a opção `target="_blank"` para abrir em uma nova aba.

Tente:

```
<a href="https://gradcollege.okstate.edu/sites/default/files/PDF_linking.pdf" target="_blank">Clique aqui para ver o link</a>
```

Comment: Da forma que você colocou, se eu desativo o PDF Viewer, ele não abre, ele pede para fazer download do arquivo. O que eu quero é algo que abra no browser(chrome) o arquivo e com o plugin desativado ou não instalado. Achei algo que faz o que eu quero e depois de testar eu posto a solução.

Comment: @pnet Não entendi porque a pessoal iria desbloquear o PDF Viewer e porque você quer força-lo a ver de qualquer maneira.

Comment: É o seguinte: O empresa tem uns 600 operadores que precisam ver documentos(relatórios) dos clientes, enquanto atendem. A matriz(EUA) não quer homologar o Chrome e no Brasil, temos a necessidade de apresentar relatórios no Chrome por força de clientes e fornecedores. Esses operadores, muitos são terceiros. Então há uma "briga" aqui entre a filial nossa e a matriz e para não parar o trabalho que já foi feito(fazer o site funcionar no chrome), nós estamos aplicando o nosso plano "B", que é usar esse recurso do jquery e contornar a falta do plugin.

Comment: Outra coisa, não que é que o pessoal vai desbloquear. O pessoal da segurança de TI já bloqueia tudo e remove o que é usado no chrome por Default. Não tem choro, se é Chrome não pode ter nada nele, nada mesmo. Eles não deixa nenhuma opção para o usuário. Usuário é apenas usuário mesmo, no bom sentido da palavra.

Answer (score 0):

Marconi, vou ver seu exemplo. Dessa forma aqui que eu peguei na internet, funcionou, usando um cara chamado ZohoViewer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.zohoviewer.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('a.embed').zohoViewer();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="Files/ISS.PDF" class="embed">Read PDF File</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Em realidade a minha solução não funcionou. Por que? Porque fui nas configurações do Chrome e lé havia um plugin PDF Viewer ativado. desativei e com o recurso acima, não funcionou. Ativo o plugin e funciona.  Aqui na empresa, a maioria dos operadores não possui o plugin PDF Viewer e procuro uma solução que funcione no "tapa" mesmo, sem plugin e sem nada. Tá osso, eu sei, mas peço ajuda dos colegas.

Comment: Da forma, com o plugin desativado não dá erro, apenas não abre o arquivo, ele sugere fazer download do arquivo para a máquina.

Comment: Fiz o download nesse link e funcionou com o plugin desativado que é o que eu quero. http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Touch-enabled-jQuery-Web-PDF-Viewer-TouchPDF.html

Comment: ja pensou em usar o [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)? veja se você consegue visualizar a pagina demo do mesmo sem o plugin ativo.

Comment: @TobyMosque, vou testar e na segunda, conforme for, eu posto. Mas o link que eu passei no comentário, parece que resolve a questão, mas preciso de mais testes.

Comment: @TobyMosque, aparentemente esse é o cara que vamos trabalhar. Mais simples o uso do que o anterior que eu peguei e muito mais completo. Ainda estamos homologando.

Comment: O PDF.JS é mantido pela Monzila e usado como visualizador padrão no Firefox, então ele já é um visualizador de PDF bastante utilizado.